# Share token (data) between Android app users

Tags: android, facebook, push-notification, share

I was wondering if anyone had a simple solution for which users of my application can share a token that the application generates for them with their friends?

Say two people install the application, I would like one person to be able to share their token with another user.

I have looked into Facebook, and the Login/Friends system would be perfect, however I cannot see a way to share the token easily.

Obviously users could email this token to each other, but that would not be a great user experience.

Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not have the token sharing on a backend server? Then users can just send requests to the server and the server can manage the sharing, either through push notifications or by polling the server for new token requests every so often. This is also a more robust way to do it, since if a user switches to a new phone (or uninstalls the app and then reinstalls), it would be trivial to get all the tokens again.

Other than that the simplest way I could see would be to let the users text or email the tokens. Again, not really a great solution, but relatively simple and it will take a lot less work.

Comment: This would be the best solution, however I'm not so good at writing server side solutions, so was looking for an alternative.

Comment: The only way it might be easier is if you can find some already written server code that you can adapt that does what I described (sorry I don't know any). If you don't have a server backend, you won't have anyway to persist data beyond what is currently on the phone. If you don't care about that, just pass the token through text or email.

Answer (score 0):

You could send a specially formatted SMS to the friend. Your app would then intercept the SMS and process it without the user seeing it. You'd need the proper permissions, of course.